# Can't import pygame to Netbeans on Mac

Tags: python, netbeans, import, module, pygame

I am running python 2.6.5 and pygame 1.9.1 It seems to me I've tried everything but it keeps showing 'module not found' errors... Please help!

Comment: "module not found?"  Which module?  Perhaps you could share the actual error message you're actually getting.  Please UPDATE the question; please don't try to post the message as a comment.

Comment: Does 'import pygame' work from the interpreter?

Comment: yes importing it from console works fine

Answer (score 1):

Well I've just finished installing it on my Mac - you have to watch out for the Python Platform under Tools and File. The default is Jython, but you want to change it to point to your python version in the Frameworks file of your Library.

Does that make sense?